# How to pass custom parameters(such as -o) to scrapy crawler

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm currently working on python2.7/Scrapy 1.8 project.
I work within a Docker container and using a

***launchable.py:***

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from spiders import addonsimilartechSpider, similartechSpider

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(similartechSpider.SimilarTechSpider)
process.crawl(addonsimilartechSpider.AddonSimilarSpider)
process.start()
```

I used to start my scrapy like this :

```
scrapy crawl <nameofmyspider> -o output.xlsx
```

I installed scrapy-xlsx and used it until now, now that I have my launchable.py I dont know how to pass 'custom' arguments through scrappy crawler (not spider).
I understand the difference between scrapy settings and spider settings, so :

```
process.crawl(similartechSpider.SimilarTechSpider, input='-o', first='test1.xlsx')
```

will likely not work right?

thanks for any of your time taken to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the corresponding Scrapy settings instead (`FEED_*`).

You can pass them to `CrawlerProcess` as a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'FEED_URI': 'output_file_name.xlsx',
    'FEED_EXPORTERS' : {'xlsx': 'scrapy_xlsx.XlsxItemExporter'},
})
```